# How to recreate cache for "APTonCD" after cleaning cache through apt-get clean?

Tags: apt, package-management, backup, synaptic, cache

I recently had to opt for cleaning my cache through `apt-get clean` after getting lots of **GPG errors** during update. But it's created another problem for me since I want to create an "APTonCD" for backup.

I want to know how I could just get all the packages I've installed on my computer so that I could include them in my APTonCD. Is it possible to achieve that by selecting all installed packages in Synaptic for reinstallation but choosing to download those files only. I hope that option will leave my installed packages intact.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will download all your currently installed packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1 | xargs -n1 sudo apt-get install --reinstall --download-only
```

Comment: nice piping....

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --get-selections` displays currently installed packages

you can do some cut on the output columns and manipulate the data however you like.  I personally prefer using apt-mirror.

Comment: OK. Is it the same as selecting all installed packages in Synaptic for reinstallation, and then choosing to download only? I'd also be glad to learn how apt-mirror functions.

Comment: the other answer is exactly what you reference in comment...apt-mirror grabs entire repositories and builds a local repo for you(keeps it updated too if you schedule a cron job).  apt-mirror is overkill for the exact aptoncd thing you are trying, but i like being able to install a given package that wasn't in my base system without a net connection.

Comment: OK. From what I understood from your comment, apt-mirror helps install even those files that haven't been installed and that too without internet.

Comment: correct.  it copies all the packages on the selected repositories